# Update an outer variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, counter

I'm creating a project where my marker move according to the value of a dice. 
[image]
The following function is responsible for that action.

```
var markerMoveFunc = () => {
    var incrementDice = 0;

    var diceIncrementer = () => {
      let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      let diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
      diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
      diceDOM.src = '/static' + '/images' + '/dice-' + dice + '.png';
      incrementDice += dice;
    };

    document
      .querySelector('.roll-btn')
      .addEventListener('click', diceIncrementer);

    var firstChild = document.querySelector('#container').childNodes[
      incrementDice
    ];
    firstChild.innerHTML += `<div class='marker'><i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></div>`;
  };
```

**The entire code**

```
function init() {
  const cards = [
    { front: 'Apple', back: 'Яблоко' },
    { front: 'Cherry', back: 'Вишня' },
    { front: 'Melon', back: 'Арбуз' },
    { front: 'Car', back: 'Машина' },
    { front: 'Book', back: 'Книга' },
    { front: 'Pen', back: 'Ручка' },
    { front: 'Nice', back: 'Прекрасный' },
    { front: 'TV', back: 'Телевизор' },
    { front: 'Mobile', back: 'Мобильный' },
    { front: 'Curious', back: 'Любопытный' }
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  const createCard = () => {
    for (var card in cards) {
      // Create an item
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      // Add class to item div
      item.className = 'item';
      // Create flip card inner elem
      var flipCardInner = document.createElement('div');
      // Add 'flip-card-inner' class
      flipCardInner.className = 'flip-card-inner';
      // Create front card elem
      var frontCardElem = document.createElement('div');
      // Add 'flip-card-front' class
      frontCardElem.className = 'flip-card-front';
      // Creat front card text
      var frontCardText = document.createTextNode(cards[card].front);
      // Append front card text to frontcard element
      frontCardElem.appendChild(frontCardText);
      // Create back card elem
      var backCardElem = document.createElement('div');
      // Add 'flip-card-front' class
      backCardElem.className = 'flip-card-back';
      // Creat back card text
      var backCardText = document.createTextNode(cards[card].back);
      // Append front card text to frontcard element
      backCardElem.appendChild(backCardText);
      // Append front card elem to flip card inner
      flipCardInner.appendChild(frontCardElem);
      // Append back card elem to flip card inner
      flipCardInner.appendChild(backCardElem);
      // Append flip card inner to item
      item.appendChild(flipCardInner);
      container.appendChild(item);
    }
  };

  createCard();

  var markerMoveFunc = () => {
    var incrementDice = 0;

    var diceIncrementer = () => {
      let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      let diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
      diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
      diceDOM.src = '/static' + '/images' + '/dice-' + dice + '.png';
      incrementDice += dice;
    };

    document
      .querySelector('.roll-btn')
      .addEventListener('click', diceIncrementer);

    var firstChild = document.querySelector('#container').childNodes[
      incrementDice
    ];
    firstChild.innerHTML += `<div class='marker'><i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></div>`;
  };

  markerMoveFunc();

  $('.item .flip-card-inner').click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.item')
      .toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).css('transform, rotateX(180deg)');
  });

  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

  var radius = 250; // adjust to move out items in and out
  var inclination = 0;
  var fields = $('.item'),
    container = $('#container'),
    width = container.width(),
    height = container.height();
  var angle = 0,
    step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;

  fields.each(function() {
    var x = Math.round(
      width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2
    );

    var y = Math.round(
      height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2
    );

    $(this).css({
      left: x + 'px',
      top: y + 'px',
      WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + inclination + 'deg)'
    });
    angle += step;
    inclination += 0;
  });
}

init();
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Ed game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="dice-holder">
      <img src="static/images/dice-1.png" alt="dice" class="dice" />

      <Button class="roll-btn">Roll dice</Button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't understand why incrementDice does not update. Could you give me an advice please?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also please post your HTML code.

Comment: HTML code is just <div id="container"></div>. I don't think there is a problem with it.

Comment: What is `document.querySelector(".roll-btn")`?

Comment: It is a roll dice button as on the picture.

Comment: can u prove the html so that we can help you better!!